# Printing text in a new file bug

Tags: c

Okay so I am trying to write this adjacency matrix into this text file but my code is just writing the first value of the adjacency matrix.

Instead of `fprint` I checked using simply `printf` and it works fine, but I can't really understand what is going wrong with printing the same thing inside a `.txt` file

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXVERTICES 10 

int main(){


  FILE* fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  int **mat;
  int num[100];
  int i,v,e,j,a,b,u,ne=1,p;

  int matrix[MAXVERTICES][MAXVERTICES];
  int cost[10][10];
  int taken[10] = {0}, min, mincost=0;

  //printf("ENter");

  fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &v, &e);

  for (int i = 0; i <e; i++)
  {
    int v1, v2;
    int weight;

    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &weight);    

    matrix[v1][v2] = matrix[v2][v1]=weight;
    //   printf("%d", weight);
  }

  //printf("Check 0");
  FILE* f;
  for (int i = 0; i<v; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<v; j++){
      f=fopen("adjacency.txt", "w");

      fprintf(f,"%d", matrix[i][j]);
    }
     fprintf(f,"\n");
  }
 fclose(f)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful.   always check the returned value (not the parameters) from fscanf() to assure the input/conversion operation(s) was successful.  there are several 'magic' numbers (10, 100) in the source.  Magic numbers are a maintenance nightmare, especially when they are not commented.  Suggest inserting appropriate #define statements, with comments, and use those #define'd names in the code.   When #define'ing a numeric value, always wrap the value in parens '(' ')' so avoid certain text replacement problems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to `fopen()` the file inside the loop, you only need to `fopen()` the file once, check that it did open, and then `fprintf()` to it in the loop.

Fix your program like this

```
FILE* file;

file = fopen("adjacency.txt", "w");
if (file != NULL)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i<v; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j<v; j++)
         {
            fprintf(f,"%d", matrix[i][j]);
         }
        fprintf(f,"\n");
     }
 }
```

Comment: with this implementation the value of the matrix is altered!